# Media query for changing images not working

Tags: css, media-queries

I've been trying to have different images show up on my main page based on screen size.  None of the solutions I've seen online are helping.  Instead, both images are showing on all screens.  Here is one of the methods I've tried.  First, in my stylesheet, I put:

```
.screen-only {
  display: block;
}

.mobile-only {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .screen-only {
    display: none;
  }

  .mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Then, in my main page, I have:

```
<div id="titleBar" class="screen-only">
  <img src="assets/images/screenpic.png"  class="screen-only" />
</div>
<div id="titleBar" class="mobile-only">
  <img src="assets/images/mobilepic.png" class="screen-only" />
</div>
```

I'm confused if I should be putting the class in the div or in the image section, but either way I put it, or if I put it twice like I did in the example here, both images show up on all sizes.

Comment: On which devices did you test this code?  Mobile phones, tablets, desktop, laptop?  Can you make this question more reproducible?

Comment: I think you only need to include the media query CSS styles in the `<div>` tags, which should automatically include everything inside those div tags.

Comment: i think that you have some other css rules that overide the css, maybe you should look for css rules for `#titlebar`. as a side note, using same ID for different elements is considered bad practice.

Comment: @am05mhz Edits shouldn't make the original question invalid.

Comment: @jhpratt isn't that the original question still valid? as it is still not working according to the poster, i edit it to avoid many answer pointing the wrong class which is not the real problem, though you are free to cancel it

Comment: You're fundamentally changing the question by changing the class, making some of the existing answers invalid.

Comment: @jhpratt ok, fair enough, although if the original poster edit it himself, those existing answer would be invalid also

Comment: Looking at #titlebar now I saw that it did have a "display:block" line so I removed it and now, the desktop image shows ok (no mobile image), but mobile still shows both.  I'm testing mobile on an iPhone 6 plus.

Answer (score 2):

you code seems correct except that your second "div" does not have the same class in the "div" and "img" tags. Your "img" tag should have a class of "mobile-only" not "screen-only"

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed it but it still doesn't work.  Both images appear on desktop as well as mobile.

Answer (score 0):

One possible source of error and confusion is you are using screen-only and mobile-only as a class names.  Maybe it is allowed but it is confusing and not hard to avoid.

Another possible error is that you have marked both images with the class screen-only.

The following is I think a bit clearer and should actually work:

in css

```
div.responsive {
    background-image: url("assets/images/screenpic.png");
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    div.responsive {
        background-image: url("assets/images/mobilepic.png");
    }
}
```

in html

```
<div id="title-bar" class="responsive"> </div>
```

here is a complete html file with inline styles that show what you are after.  I have used images from SO just to show that it works, you should replaace the img tags with your images.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
div.responsive {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
#mobile-title {
    display: none;
}
#desktop-title {
    display: block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
div.responsive {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
#mobile-title {
    display: block;
}
#desktop-title {
    display: none;
}

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mobile-title" class="responsive">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LROA.png?s=32&amp;g=1" width="32" height="32">
</div>
<div id="desktop-title" class="responsive">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/598b1b70f462d6708ff9a459a102d500?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG&amp;f=1" alt="" width="32" height="32">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now nothing shows.  (I already have a background image, basically a texture, repeating across the screen, so I'm guessing now there's an issue there.)  My code for that is:   background: url(assets/images/background.png) repeat;

Comment: I am adding some more code to make it clearer, if it still doesnt work then there must be some style that is bleeding into your elements - if you cant find the problem, you will have to post your css and possibly your html.

Comment: I tried @flurbius code (both with the css on the stylesheet as well as inline), and had no results. Both images pop up.  Here is a [link](http://www.haloedbane.com) to the page I've been trying to do this with.  The issue is with the images titled "haloedbane.png" (for mobile) and "haloedbane_sfa.png" (for desktop).  Neither will show right now.

Comment: Sorry I didnt get back to you earlier, Ive just had a look at your page,and I guess you have changed the code because I found no reference to haloedbane_sfa.png, the other image is referenced and is visible all the time, and your stylesheet doesnt have an @media section.

Comment: Thank you for taking another look!  I just put all those lines back in so you can see what's going wrong.  I can PM you my stylesheet if you'd like as well. (I added the viewport instructions at one point as well and that didn't help either, plus it made the mobile screen version look really off, so I took it out).